# Facebook login with JS

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get a login via Javascript SDK from Facebook. 
I just have never done something like that.

So this is my source code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit=function(){
    FB.init({
      appId  : '1234567890',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log('Logged in.');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Logging in...');
    FB.login();
  }
});
</script>
<input type="button" onClick="FB.getLoginStatus();" value="Login" />
</body>
</html>
```

But sadly this is doing... nothing :(
There is nothing I can see in the console and nothing displayed (even if I push the Login-Button)

Maybe someone could help me?!

Best regards,
Kartilia

Comment: There should be errors in the console – because for one thing, you are calling `FB.getLoginStatus` before the SDK is even initialized. And calling it via onclick on the button won’t have any visible effect at all, since you’re not passing a callback function that would handle the result at this point.

Comment: I don't get any errors...
But I do have the Init-function there. And even if it's loaded only when everything else loaded with the button it should be before I push it?!
I'm really new to javascript :)

Comment: You do have the FB.init call there – but it will only be executed “later”, because it is inside the `fbAsyncInit`, that fire when the SDK has finished loading. Your FB.getLoginStatus call belongs into that as well, after the FB.init. And again – clicking your button won’t do much, since in that place you do not have a callback function for getLoginStatus.